# DataContext issues with ListBox after changes to MainWindow.xaml

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, mvvm

I am new to WPF and the MVVM design pattern this month, and more than a little out of practice in general.  To learn, I've been playing around with textboxes, rectangles, and ways to display them in a window.  I began with Ashley Davis' excellent "Simple Drag Selection in WPF" tutorial, which walks through creating a view model for a collection of rectangles, binding a listbox to said collection, and styling the listbox with a canvas, creating a data template for the rectangles, as well as basic "rubber band" selection logic.

I have since built on this tutorial to improve the drag selection so that it behaves much more like selection does in windows explorer, and to allow resizing the rectangles from the corners or edges.

All was well until I changed the MainWindow.xaml in an effort to include a column on the side for various buttons and controls, thus moving the "editor surface" grid from inside a 1x1 grid on the main window to a column of a 1x2 grid, moving the data template to the grid's resources (since it will be the only element in the window that needs it). As soon as I did this, subroutines that I wrote which interact with the listbox started misbehaving--rubber band selection no longer works.  There's no visual indication that listbox items are being selected (they were highlighted previously), and interrogating listBox.SelectedItems.Count after a drag-selection mouseUp event returns a zero.

After some experimentation, reading many questions on this site and sections of my WPF Unleashed book, and going over the msdn databinding overview, as of this morning I still cannot find my mistake(s).  I believe it is a data binding mistake or incorrect data context.

Some details about the view models involved:

DataFieldViewModel

...implements INotifyPropertyChanged and exposes properties for its (in this case a rectangle and a textbox) X,Y position, width, height, visibility, and selection status (a way to track it across several rubber band selection operations)

PageViewModel

...implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and has among other things an ObservableCollection of type DataFieldViewModel, called DataFields, and exposes it as a ReadOnly Property.

Here's a look at MainWindow.xaml.vb and one of the broken subs:

```
Namespace EditorUI


'
' The main window of the editor.
'
Partial Public Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    '
    ' Temporary.  Will be replaced with a collection of pages eventually
    '
    Private Pages As PageViewModel
```

(remaining data members and properties snipped for brevity)

```
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        Pages = New PageViewModel

    End Sub
```

(and here's one of the subs with issues)

```
 '
    ' Select all the data fields that intersect the selection rectangle.
    ' Remove any selected data fields which do not.
    '
    Private Sub ApplyDragSelectionRectangle()

        If (LeftMouseDrag) Then

            Dim selectionRectangle As New Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(selectionRectangleBorder), _
                                               Canvas.GetTop(selectionRectangleBorder), _
                                               selectionRectangleBorder.Width, _
                                               selectionRectangleBorder.Height)

            '
            ' Find and select all the list box items.
            '
            For Each dataFieldViewModel As DataFieldViewModel In Me.Pages.GetDataFields
                Dim hitBox As New Rect(dataFieldViewModel.hbX, _
                                       dataFieldViewModel.hbY, _
                                       dataFieldViewModel.hbWidth, _
                                       dataFieldViewModel.hbHeight)

                If (selectionRectangle.IntersectsWith(hitBox)) Then
                    If (dataFieldViewModel.ExistingSelection) Then
                        '
                        ' data field is already part of an existing selection; unselect it
                        '
                        Me.DataFieldListBox.SelectedItems.Remove(dataFieldViewModel)
                    Else
                        Me.DataFieldListBox.SelectedItems.Add(dataFieldViewModel)
                    End If
                End If
                If Not (selectionRectangle.IntersectsWith(hitBox)) Then
                    If (dataFieldViewModel.ExistingSelection) Then
                        '
                        ' data field was part of an existing selection; reselect it
                        '
                        Me.DataFieldListBox.SelectedItems.Add(dataFieldViewModel)
                    Else
                        Me.DataFieldListBox.SelectedItems.Remove(dataFieldViewModel)
                    End If
                End If

            Next
        Else
            dragSelectionCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            '
            ' update all data fields' existing selection status to the new
            ' selection (first set them all to false to catch data fields 
            ' that were removed)
            '
            For Each dataFieldViewModel As DataFieldViewModel In Me.DataFieldListBox.Items
                dataFieldViewModel.ExistingSelection = False
            Next
            For Each dataFieldViewModel As DataFieldViewModel In Me.DataFieldListBox.SelectedItems
                dataFieldViewModel.ExistingSelection = True
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

Finally, here is the XAML in its entirety:

```
<Window x:Class="EditorUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor_UI_Experiments.EditorUI"
    Title="Editor UI Experiments" 
    Width="900"
    Height="600"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" 

    >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="778*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button
            Grid.Column="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="25"
            Content="Explode :D"
            Name="Button1" 

            />

        <Grid
            Name="EditorSurface"
            Grid.Column="1"
            MouseDown="Editor_MouseDown"
            MouseUp="Editor_MouseUp"
            MouseMove="Editor_MouseMove"

            >

            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding GetPageImage}" />

            </Grid.Background>

            <Grid.DataContext>

                <local:PageViewModel/>

            </Grid.DataContext>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <!--
                A data template that defines the visuals for a data field.
                -->
                <DataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type local:DataFieldViewModel}"
                    >
                    <!-- 
                    The data field is embedded in a Grid so that we can set the Margin
                    The margin is set so that the ListBox item selection fits nicely around the Rectangle.
                    -->
                    <Grid
                    Margin="0,2,2,2"
                        >
                        <!-- 
                        text box where the data field's response lives (it could be a Database tag,
                        or a check mark, or custom response)
                        -->
                        <TextBox
                        Width="{Binding Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                        Background="LightBlue"
                        Cursor="IBeam"
                        MouseDown="TextBox_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove"
                        Text="Example Text"
                            />
                        <!-- 
                        rectangle that lives on top of the text field to aid in positioning the data field
                        -->
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="{Binding Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                        Stroke="LightBlue"
                        StrokeThickness="5"
                        Fill="White"
                        Opacity="0.5"
                        Cursor="SizeAll"
                        MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Rectangle_MouseMove"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                            />
                        <!--
                        Thumb "handles" to give the user a way to resize the data field
                        -->
                        <!-- 
                        These four live in the corners of a data field and allow resizing on
                        X and Y simultaneously
                        -->
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="7"
                        Height="7"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="-1,-1,0,0"
                        Cursor="SizeNWSE"
                        Fill="LightGray"
                        Stroke="Gray"
                        Opacity="0.6"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="7"
                        Height="7"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0,-1,-1,0"
                        Cursor="SizeNESW"
                        Fill="LightGray"
                        Stroke="Gray"
                        Opacity="0.6"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="7"
                        Height="7"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="-1,0,0,-1"
                        Cursor="SizeNESW"
                        Fill="LightGray"
                        Stroke="Gray"
                        Opacity="0.6"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="7"
                        Height="7"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0,0,-1,-1"
                        Cursor="SizeNWSE"
                        Fill="LightGray"
                        Stroke="Gray"
                        Opacity="0.6"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <!--
                        These four live along the data field's edges and allow resizing in the X
                        or Y direction only.  They have zero opacity to avoid visual clutter
                        -->
                        <Rectangle
                        Height="5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="7,0,7,0"
                        Cursor="SizeNS"
                        Fill="Yellow"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <Rectangle
                        Height="5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="7,0,7,0"
                        Cursor="SizeNS"
                        Fill="Yellow"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="0,7,0,7"
                        Cursor="SizeWE"
                        Fill="Yellow"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />
                        <Rectangle
                        Width="5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0,7,0,7"
                        Cursor="SizeWE"
                        Fill="Yellow"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                        MouseDown="Thumb_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="Thumb_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="Thumb_MouseMove"

                            />                            
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </Grid.Resources>
            <!--
            This ListBox presents the data fields

            The data template that defines the visuals for each data field is in the 
            resources section at the start of this file.
            -->

            <ListBox
                x:Name="DataFieldListBox"
                ItemsSource="{Binding GetDataFields}"
                SelectionMode="Extended"
                Background="Transparent"

                >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style
                            TargetType="ListBoxItem"

                            >
                            <Setter
                            Property="Canvas.Left"
                            Value="{Binding X}"

                            />
                            <Setter
                            Property="Canvas.Top"
                            Value="{Binding Y}"

                            />
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>

            <!--
            Render a drag selection rectangle using a Canvas with a border
            -->
            <Canvas
            x:Name="dragSelectionCanvas"
            Visibility="Collapsed"

                >
                <Border 
                x:Name="selectionRectangleBorder"
                BorderBrush="Blue"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="LightBlue"
                CornerRadius="1"
                Opacity="0.5"

                />
            </Canvas>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I'm sure my code is riddled with novice mistakes, but it's been fun so far. Hope to improve quickly and maybe turn this into something useful.  Feedback and insight are most welcome.  If someone happens to find where I'm going wrong, you'll have my gratitude.

-Tom

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact you are defining the Grid's `DataContext` in the XAML, but your drag event is referencing an object in the code-behind. So your ListBox is binding to the XAML copy of `PageViewModel`, while your code-behind is working with a different copy of `PageViewModel`

Comment: Hm, I was unaware the XAML would have a separate copy/instance.  Could this be fixed by binding its data context to the code-behind copy somehow?  Or perhaps doing so in the PageViewModel constructor with DataContext = Me ...?

Comment: By the way, I suppose it's a little odd for a grid to even have a data context, since it doesn't have anything to do with the data itself.  Eventually I want to be able to scroll through a stack of several Pages, maybe another listbox is in order.

Comment: Anything that says "{Binding ...}" is referencing the `DataContext`. For example, `{Binding GetDataFields}` is binding to a property that exists on `PageViewModel` called `GetDataFields`. I'd suggest removing the `DataContext` property from the XAML and instead setting it in the code-behind, such as `Me.DataContext = Pages`

Comment: That's done it!  Setting data context in the code-behind seems like it runs counter to MVVM's ideal separation of look and logic, but it's definitely good enough until I have a better grip on Binding's intended use.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad that worked out :) I moved the comments to an and actual answer to answer your question. Also, you're right you usually shouldn't be setting the `DataContext` in code-behind *unless* its the application startup code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the fact you are defining the Grid's `DataContext` in the XAML, but your drag event is referencing an object in the code-behind. So your `ListBox` is binding to the XAML copy of `PageViewModel`, while your code-behind is working with a different copy of `PageViewModel`

I'd suggest removing the `DataContext` property from the XAML and instead setting it in the code-behind, such as `Me.DataContext = Pages`

Just keep in mind that its usually bad practice to be setting the `DataContext` in code-behind unless it's the application startup code.